# How to apply vba to all worksheets no matter if it is active or not

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to apply a VBA to a workbook with multiple worksheets where `sheetnames` are variable but fail.

MY code only works on active worksheet.

Could please help me to see what is the problem?

```
Sub sample_code()
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        With ws
           Range("A1").Value = "test each worksheet"
        End With
    Next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: He's missing the `.` in front of `Range`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, can't test this right now, but does the following work?

```
Sub sample_code()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        With ws
            .Range("A1") = "test each worksheet"
            ' (.Range("A1").Value is okay too)
        End With
    Next ws
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

*You should fully qualify your `Cell A1` range - example **`.Range("A1")`***

***[Intro to VBA: The Excel Object Hierarchy ( Jon Acampora )](https://www.excelcampus.com/vba/macros-explained-part-2/)***

*[Look into VBA objects which are organized in a hierarchy so it makes them easier to reference an object](https://www.excelcampus.com/vba/macros-explained-part-2/)*

[image]

*At the top it is the Excel Application. All the objects within Excel are members or sub-members of the Application object.*

[image]

*The dots between each word allow us to reference members of the hierarchy from top down*

---

> ***Remember VBA allows us to make assumptions when referencing objects. If you don’t specify the workbook or worksheet in a line of code, then VBA assumes you are referring to the active workbook and active worksheet.***
>
> ---

*For example, the following line of code will clear the values and formulas of all the cells on the active worksheet.*

> ```
> Cells.ClearContents
> ```

*If you don’t tell VBA which sheet in which workbook you want to clear, then this could spell disaster! You can’t undo that action.*

*So you would want to qualify this line of code to tell VBA which workbook and worksheet you are referring to.*

> ```
> Workbooks("Book1.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells.ClearContents
> ```