# Error on second if when sending email

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

The code successfully sends the first email, but I am encountering an error on the second.

> [Run-time error '-2147221238 (8004010a)': The item has been moved or deleted].

My goal is to use the button to automatically send reminder emails based on the criteria from the IF statements. The debug references the `.To = Recipient` line.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim objOutlook As Object
Dim objEmail As Object
Dim Row As Integer
Dim Recipient As String
Dim Requestor As String
Dim CQID As String
Dim lastRow As Long

Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set objEmail = objOutlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)

lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

With objEmail
    For Row = 2 To lastRow
        If Cells(Row, 12).Value = "10" And IsEmpty(Cells(Row, 13).Value) = True Then 'Prepares and sends email after 10 days and no reminder has already been sent. The second constraint is to prevent multiple emails from being sent if the button is pressed multiple times in the day.
            Recipient = Cells(Row, 14).Value
            Requestor = Cells(Row, 15).Value
            CQID = Cells(Row, 1).Value
            .To = Recipient '<---Debug reference
            .CC = Requestor
            .Subject = "Update Requested for " & CQID
            .Body = "Please send us an update on " & CQID
            '.Display
            .Send
            Cells(Row, 13).Value = "1st Reminder Sent" 'Prepares constraint for second reminder
        End If
        If Cells(Row, 12).Value = "15" And Cells(Row, 13).Value = "1st Reminder Sent" Then
            Recipient = Cells(Row, 14).Value
            Requestor = Cells(Row, 15).Value
            .To = Recipient
            .CC = Requestor
            .Subject = "Update Requested for " & CQID
            .Body = "Please send us an update on " & CQID
            '.Display
            .Send
            Cells(Row, 13).Value = "2nd Reminder Sent"
            End If
    Next Row
End With

Set objEmail = Nothing
Set objOutlook = Nothing

End Sub
```

Any help with the direct issue or suggestions for general improvements are greatly appreciated.

Comment: You'll need another `Set objEmail = objOutlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)` for each iteration of your loop - after your first `.Send` that item is gone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*No need for second set `objEmail` to Creates a new Outlook item, simply move it inside your loop*

> ```
>    Dim Row As Long
>     For Row = 2 To lastRow        
>         Dim objEmail As Object
>         Set objEmail = objOutlook.CreateItem(0)
> ```

*Also its very impotent to specify the workbook or worksheet in the code when referencing   **`Cells(Row`***

*Example*

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim objOutlook As Object
    Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    Dim Sht As Worksheet
    Set Sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    With Sht
        Dim lastRow As Long
            lastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

        Dim Row As Long
        For Row = 2 To lastRow
            Dim objEmail As Object
            Set objEmail = objOutlook.CreateItem(0)

            If Sht.Cells(Row, 12).Value = "10" And _
                 IsEmpty(Sht.Cells(Row, 13).Value) = True Then

                Dim Recipient As String
                Dim Requestor As String
                Dim CQID As String

                With objEmail
                     Recipient = Sht.Cells(Row, 14).Value
                     Requestor = Sht.Cells(Row, 15).Value
                     CQID = Sht.Cells(Row, 1).Value
                    .To = Recipient
                    .CC = Requestor
                    .Subject = "Update Requested for "
                    .Body = "Please send us an update on "
                    .Display
    '                .Send
                     Sht.Cells(Row, 13).Value = "1st Reminder Sent"
                End With '<-email

            Else

                If Sht.Cells(Row, 12).Value = "15" And _
                   Sht.Cells(Row, 13).Value = "1st Reminder Sent" Then

                    With objEmail
                         Recipient = Sht.Cells(Row, 14).Value
                         Requestor = Sht.Cells(Row, 15).Value
                        .To = Recipient
                        .CC = Requestor
                        .Subject = "Update Requested for " & CQID
                        .Body = "Please send us an update on " & CQID
                        .Display
    '                    .Send
                         Sht.Cells(Row, 13).Value = "2nd Reminder Sent"
                    End With '<-email
                End If

            End If
        Next Row
    End With '<-sht

    Set objEmail = Nothing
    Set objOutlook = Nothing

End Sub
```

> ***[See fully qualified examples](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49548558/4539709)***

Comment: Ah now that makes sense! It worked very well, thank you.