# Using Next and Previous buttons in VBA

Tags: vba, userform

I am trying to learn how to use VBA by watching YouTube. I created a userform in which has command buttons that you can look at next data and previous data that was inputted on the sheet. For some reason if I have another excel document open it is capturing that data as well. Does anyone know why it is doing that?

Comment: Can you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54098578/edit) your question with the code you're using?

Comment: Always Specify the workbook or worksheet your working on in a line of code

Comment: look at the links on this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/49548558/4539709